# do not understand why I cannot free an array

Tags: c

Again with the memory allocation...

I don't seem to understand why my call to free is not working on the array in the object. It makes sense to me, but I get a segmentation fault. All I would like is to free the min_array and the array in the stack in the minStackFree function. Does anyone understand why this could be happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    int * array;
    int array_idx; // is 'top'

    int * min_array;
    int min_idx;

} MinStack;

MinStack * minStackCreate() {
    
    MinStack * obj = malloc(sizeof(MinStack*));

    //initialize the stacks
    obj->array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int*));
    obj->min_array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int*));

    //initialize the index
    obj->array_idx = -1;
    obj->min_idx = -1;

}  

void minStackFree(MinStack* obj) {
    free(obj->min_array); // ************PROBLEM
    free(obj->array); // ************PROBLEM
    free(obj); // OK
}
```

Comment: `MinStack * obj = malloc(sizeof *obj);`  You were only allocating 8-bytes (or 4-bytes on x86) for a pointer. E.g. `sizeof(MinStack*)` is `sizeof(a_pointer)` (you may have other issues -- this was just the first that caught my eye) If you don't `return obj;` how is the allocated memory ever used back in the caller?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(MinStack*))` most probably this is the issue. You need `sizeof(MinStack)` without the `*`

Comment: A common idiom that greatly helps to avoid that error is to write: `MinStack * obj = malloc(sizeof *obj);`  Note that this does not avoid the other common error of forgetting to multiply by a count, so it might be better practice to write `MinStack *obj = malloc(1 * sizeof *obj);`

Comment: Thank you guys, it was definitely that, and haha, yes, I did need to return the obj.

Comment: You've posted three questions and every one of them has a non-void function that's missing a `return` statement. I suggest you turn up the compiler warning setting(s).

Comment: Please remember the *minimal* part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a matter of **if** `malloc()` will fail returning `NULL`, it is a matter of **when**. You must always validate EVERY allocation. Otherwise you risk *Undefined Behavior* (and likely a SegFault) if you fail to catch the allocation failure. A simple check is all that is needed, e.g.

```
#define ARRSZ 10000     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

MinStack *minStackCreate (void) {
    
    MinStack *obj = malloc (sizeof *obj);       /* use dereference pointer for typesize */
    if (!obj) {                                 /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-obj");
        return NULL;
    }

    obj->array = malloc (ARRSZ * sizeof *obj->array); /* dereference pointer for typesize */
    if (!obj->array) {                                /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-obj->array");
        free (obj);                                   /* free prior allocaitons */
        return NULL;
    }
    obj->min_array = malloc (ARRSZ * sizeof *obj->min_array);   /* ditto */
    if (!obj->min_array) {                                      /* ditto */
        perror ("malloc-obj->min_array");
        free (obj->array);                            /* free prior allocaitons */
        free (obj);
        return NULL;
    }

    //initialize the index
    obj->array_idx = -1;
    obj->min_idx = -1;

    return obj;                 /* return allocated pointer */
}
```

As [@chux-ReinstateMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) points out, with multiple allocations in your function, should an allocation fail, you must free the memory allocated in the function prior to the point of failure, before returning `NULL` to avoid a memory leak. Once `NULL` is returned, you would have no way to reach the allocations that occurred prior to the point of failure.

Don't use *Magic-Numbers* (e.g. `10000`) in your code. If you need a constant, `#define` one, or use a global `enum` for the same purpose. That way if your needs change, you have one single location to update and the change is seen throughout your code.

Readability. The `'*'` dereference operator goes with the variable not the type. Why? Readability:

```
int* a, b, c;
```

most certainly does not declare 3-pointers to `int`, writing

```
int *a, b, c;
```

makes it abundantly clear that a single pointer to `int` and two integers are being declared.

Use the dereferenced pointer to set typesize. If you do that, you will never get the typesize wrong, e.g.

```
MinStack *obj = malloc (sizeof *obj);
```

and

```
obj->array = malloc (ARRSZ * sizeof *obj->array);
obj->min_array = malloc (ARRSZ * sizeof *obj->min_array);
```

While simple structs with the declaration in front of you may be easy to set the `sizeof(type)`, when you are 1000 lines down in your code using complex types, things will not be so easy and it is easy to guess wrong.

With those changes, and returning `obj` on success or `NULL` on failure from `minStackCreate()` and the remainder compiles without warning.

Comment: If one is to return from a failed allocation such as `if (!obj->array) { ... return NULL;`, good to first `free(obj)` to not leak memory.  A failed `if (!obj->min_array) {` gets more complicated.  To simplify,code could perform all allocations and then on any error, free all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- Oh right you are!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue was I needed to change:

```
MinStack * obj = malloc(sizeof(MinStack*));

//initialize the stacks
obj->array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int*));
obj->min_array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int*));
```

to

```
MinStack * obj = malloc(sizeof(MinStack));

//initialize the stacks
obj->array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int));
obj->min_array = malloc(10000*sizeof(int));
return obj;
```

Comment: How is the memory allocated for `obj` ever used back in the caller? You must validate EVERY allocation.